# python equivalent of this short java code

Tags: java, python

I'm writing a socket server in python. It needs to send acknowledgement to the client module. Quote from the protocol description:

> "[...]server should determine if it would accept data from this
>   module. If yes server will reply to module 01 if not 00."

I implemented this in python as:

```
connection.send('01')
```

It isn't working, so I checked the java implementation of the server:

```
        byte[] answer = {
            0x01};
        out.write(answer);
        out.flush();
```

I wonder whether it's the same or not?
The System.out.write(answer); doesn't seem to output a thing to the console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're sending two bytes, `0x30` followed by `0x31`, whereas the Java code is sending just one byte, `0x01`.

Try the following instead:

```
connection.send('\x01')
```

In case you're wondering where the `0x30` and `0x31` came from, they are [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes for the characters `'0'` and `'1'`.

Comment: `connection.send('\x01')` maybe?

Comment: @ulidtko: Same thing (the two are exactly equivalent).

Comment: @aix, but `'\x01'` is much more closer to Java's `byte[] {0x01}`.